# Draggable inside wysiwyg editor

Tags: jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg, draggable

I'm using TinyMCE as my WYSIWYG editor and I want the users to be able to insert images with absolute positions and let them place them wherever they want within the editor, so I used the jQuery Draggable plugin. When I test the Draggable on an image outside the WYSIWYG editor it works great, but inside it, it doesn't work at all..

Any idea how to fix it? I'm also open for more suggestions on how to implement this image positioning

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any jQuery plugin.

Just enable the absolute position (fourth row, fourth icon) on the image and then you can drag it around as long as you're using IE or Firefox (Webkit browsers lack several features for WYSIWYG editors)